# Dissipate quickly an inductance energy

Tags: inductance, coil, transient-suppression

The desirate goal here would be to apply a current throught a weak inductance (< 60µH) at at least 500kHz and producing as much as possible a square current figure.
To do so I have to dissipate the energy of the coil quickly when the power is cut in order to inject again the current later.

I took a look on the "flyback diode" placed in derivation of the coil and it works great (under 20V test voltage), but the inductance current fall time seems to be slower than using 51V Zener diodes mass-connected on the low side of the inductance.

But the Zener solution gives much more fluctuation (rest of the inductance energy trapped?).
Are TVS diodes another solution in this case?

Here is the (simplified) final expected design without the dissipation circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft2eP5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is a H bridge to invert polarity on the coil when the power is cut (in order to discharge faster the coil) could be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The desirate goal here would be to apply a current throught a weak
>   inductance (< 60µH) at at least 500kHz and producing as much as
>   possible a square current figure.

The basic formula for an inductor is V = L di/dt and this means that if the voltage is constant, current rises linearly at a rate given by V/L amps per second: -

[image]

So to get the current rising very very quickly (in order to generate the fast edge of a square wave) you need a voltage that is very, very high initially. Then it needs to rapidly fall back to zero in a very short time to make di/dt zero. With di/dt now zero, the initial current produced by the massive ramp in voltage, is maintained in the inductor.

Then you need to do exactly the same but with a negative very, very high voltage that rapidly falls back to zero volts. This is usually achieved by open circuiting the inductor. Anthing that impedes the creation of a really big back-emf will slow down the edges of the square wave and ruin the "desirate goal".

Step and repeat.

Given that your operating frequency is 500 kHz (2 us period) I expect you might want your current edges to be no more 100 ns long. So, what voltage do you need to apply for 200 ns across a 60 uH inductor to get (say) 1 amp flowing? Go back to the basic formula V = L di/dt. di/dt is 1 amp per 200 ns or 5,000,000 amps per second. Multiply this by L (60 uH) and the applied voltage should be 300 volts. If you want 10 amps then you'll need 3000 volts. If you want 1 amp in 10 ns then you'll also want to apply 3000 volts.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to dissipate the energy of the coil is to put nothing across it.  Anything put across it that allows current to continue to flow will slow down the energy dissipation.  The reason for the high voltage is because the energy is being dissipated so quickly.

Comment: I see, but I can't go over 600/700V without destroying the mosfet (800V max).

Comment: You have the wrong transistor. Use one intended for the horizontal deflection stage of a CRT TV. They have exactly the same problem you have. E.g BUH517, something like this.